# Can I transmit a func from parent to child in reactnavigation 6?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Have a nice day.

Can I transmit a func from parent to child in reactnavigation 6?

Maybe somethings like **this**:

```
onPress={function =>
 navigation.navigate({
  name: LANGUAGES.label_people_component,
  params: function,
  merge: true,
 })
}
```

Tks all.

Comment: I've tested it , we couldn't do this , maybe the objet passed to the next screen must be a basic value like  : true /fale , a string or int .

Comment: i think you can, try passing the function in an object . like this
onPress={function =>
 navigation.navigate({
  name: LANGUAGES.label_people_component,
  params: { myfun : ()=>{} } ,
  merge: true,
 })
}

Comment: @ANDRIAMANAMPISOAA.M. I think so. But I wish that we will have a way with it. tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can put the function into params

```
onPress={() =>
 navigation.navigate({
  name: LANGUAGES.label_people_component,
  params: {
            ...params,
            function: () => {
                        console.log('this is a function');
                      },
          }
 })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/),

> We recommend that the params you pass are JSON-serializable. That way,
> you'll be able to use state persistence and your screen components
> will have the right contract for implementing deep linking.

React Navigation parameters work like query parameters in websites in 6.x I believe, the ideal way to do this now is to use Context API where you have a single source of information.

You can also use a state management library such as [redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux) or [mobx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobx) in cases where you have a large number of stores and actions to manipulate them.